# C++ Newbie questions

Tags: c++

My task:

> Write the following program: The user is asked to enter 2 floating point numbers (use doubles). The user is then asked to enter one of the following mathematical symbols: `+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`. The program computes the answer on the two numbers the user entered and prints the results. If the user enters an invalid symbol, the program should print nothing.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int introducir()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return a;
}

bool simbolo(char x)
{
    if (x == '+')
        return true;
    if  (x == '-')
        return true;
    if (x == '*')
        return true;
    if (x == '/')
        return true;
    return false;    
}

void operar(char x, int a, int b)
{
    if (x == '+')
        cout << a+b;
    if  (x == '-')
        cout << a-b;
    if (x == '*')
        cout << a*b;
    if (x == '/')
        cout << a/b;
    else cout << "INVALID OPERATION SIMBOL";

}

int main()
{
    cout << "insert 2 numbers"<< endl;
    int a =introducir();
    int b= introducir();
    cout << "introduce one of these simbols : +,-,* o /." << endl;
    char x;
    cin >> x;
    bool primo= simbolo(x);
    {
        if (primo) {
            cout << "simbol is valid" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "invalid simbol" << endl;
        }
        cout << "operation result is:";
   }
   operar(x,a,b);
}
```

If the symbol is not in (`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`), I want it to return a message "INVALID OPERATION SIMBOL"; however it returns it even if the symbols are valid.  How do I fix that?

Comment: look up `else if`, or better, a `switch` statement.

Comment: Now is a great time to start learning how to use your debugger. Seriously, it will do you huge favors in the long run.

Comment: Seriously downvoters; it may be a very basic question, but it includes full code to reproduce the problem as well as a description of the intended behaviour. Not the greatest question in the world, but I don't think it deserves that many downvotes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hover over downvote button, and look at the tool-tip. "does not show any research effort" suits this question pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've written it, the `else` only applies to the final `if`.

Change to

```
if (x == '+'){
    cout << a+b;
} else if  (x == '-'){
    cout << a-b;
} else if (x == '*'){
    cout << a*b;
} else if (x == '/'){
    cout << a/b;
} else { 
    cout << "INVALID OPERATION SIMBOL";
}
```

and similar for the other `if` statements. (You could even consider refactoring to a `switch` block.) The braces are not entirely necessary but I've put them in for clarity.